# Why isn't my Discord status checker working as expected?

Tags: python, discord.py

## Code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.status != after.status or before.activity != after.activity:
        if after.status != Status.offline: 
            role_id = # role id
            role = after.guild.get_role(role_id)
            if role:
                if any(status in after.status.name.lower() for status in status_list) or (after.activity is not None and 'status word' in after.activity.name.lower()):
                    await after.add_roles(role)
                    print(f'added role to {after.name}')
                else:
                    await after.remove_roles(role)
                    print(f'removed role from {after.name}')
```

I have checked role id and status but it didnt work. Could someone tell me whats wrong with it?

Comment: please explain with more details what you expect , and what it does

Comment: Please check [ask] and [edit] your question. "doesn't work" is not a helpful problem description. What happens when you run your code and what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Sorry for not adding info about it, i expected it to check through members status and if it contains lets say "chasir" it gives them a role using the roles id

Comment: The code gives no error but it also doesnt print when i change my status

Comment: I have checked and it didnt give me the role, i have checked the role id and status supoosed to be.